# Releasing Returned object Error in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management

I have this code wherein I allocate a NSMutableIndexSet and return the object inside this set to be used for other methods. Here is the code:

> NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet new];

```
for (NSNumber * number in bookmarksArray)
{
    [indexes addIndex:[number intValue]];
}

return indexes;
```

Upon researching on how to release returned objects, I edited the code above to this:

> return [indexes autorelease];

However, it gave me an error saying that the message was sent to a deallocated instance. What should I do about this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem maybe like the instance you got from this method is not retained if you set it to ivar or so.

```
return [indexes autorelease]; //this is ok.
```

but within other methods, you call this method to get the indexes, if you want the returned instance indexes to be remain out of that method, you should retain it. because the instance you got is autoreleased, it will dealloced out of the method generally.(next run loop here)

```
NSMutableIndexSet *iVarIndexes;

- (void)otherMethod
{
    iVarIndexes = [[self getBookmarkIndexes] retain]; //for later use
}
```

Comment: This is actually the problem. Thanks for answering though! :D

Answer (score 2):

Autoreleased instances are released when the run loop gets to them (or when you drain your autorelease pool manually). This means that the method that receives the instance of `NSMutableIndexSet` returned from your method needs to retain it before relinquishing the control to the run loop. Otherwise the instance will get released, rendering whatever references that you might have invalid.

There is a shortcut for calling `[NSMutableIndexSet new]` and then autoreleasing the instance: you can invoke `indexSet` class method like this:

```
NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
// Populate the indexes...
return indexes;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) then you should use:

```
- (NSMutableIndexSet *)bookmarkIndexes
{
    NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
    for (NSNumber *number in bookmarksArray)
    {
        [indexes addIndex:[number intValue]];
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

If you are not using ARC then you do indeed need to auto release:

```
- (NSMutableIndexSet *)bookmarkIndexes
{
    NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [[[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (NSNumber *number in bookmarksArray)
    {
        [indexes addIndex:[number intValue]];
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

Comment: You might want to move `autorelease` to the top, as in `[[[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init] autorelease]`, as this will release the object even in case of early return (or raised exceptions).  Or you can use `[NSMutableIndexSet indexSet]` as a shortcut.

Comment: Hrmm... I've never actually thought of it that way before, thinking the difference was mostly preference. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: The method should *not* be called `getIndexes`;  the `get` prefix is reserved for pass-by-reference parameterized methods.  It should just be `indices` or `bookmarkIndices`.